# How to Count data in for loop nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to Count data in for loop nodejs

```
var service_count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    service_count += i;  
    console.log('service_charge_count: =====> '+service_count);
}
```

Comment: what's the type of data?

Comment: what are you getting as an output and what do you expect to get?

Comment: What's the input data and what's the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `i` to your variable, you're adding in the first loop 0, in the second loop 1, in the third loop 2. So you're not counting anything.

```
var service_count=0;
for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
    service_count++;
}
console.log('service_charge_count: =====> '+service_count);
```

By that you'll see how many iterations has had the loop. If the final value of service_count is the length of the variable `res` you can do this:

```
var service_count = res.length;
console.log('service_charge_count: =====> '+service_count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `i` with `service_count`, then you can change your code with:

```
for(let service_count  = 0; service_count  < res.length; service_count ++){
    console.log('service_charge_count: =====> ' + service_count);
}
```

Or I think that you `service_count` is `res.length`, therefore, you can do:

```
let service_count = res.length;
console.log(service_count);
```